# Persistent data storage Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is the data contained in applicationdata.curent.localsetting.values persistent?
As in, will they contain the same values that were previously set if I were to restart the phone and my application?

I don't have a device to test this on but I believe it doesn't. What would be the most efficient way to store my applications data for various settings?

Thank You.

Comment: There are couple of choices - [here is a good overview at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx). You may think about [RoamingData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) which are backed to the cloud and can persist little longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is persistent. Just don't forget do call its `Save()` method otherwise you'll all modifications.

However I'd use `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings` which is backed to OneDrive and in case of Universal App is shared between phone's and PC's versions.

Comment: Under what condition is the data removed?

Comment: AFAIK, data is only removed when application is uninstalled or it is specifically removed (or changed) by the app itself. Other apps cannot access your app's data.